# How to check if groups of data are connected in python

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine we have a data set like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4], 'Number':[234, 43, 455, 112, 45, 234, 982, 41, 112, 46, 109, 4]})
```

Now, if you run the code above, you'll see that ID's 1,2 and 3 are all 'connected', i.e. ID 1 is connected to ID 2 via Number == 234, and ID 2 is connected to ID 3 via Number == 112. But ID 4 is not connected to these other 3 ID's. So I would like to have a df_final like this

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4], 'Number':[234, 43, 455, 112, 45, 234, 982, 41, 112, 46, 109, 4], 'Group':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2]})
```

My data set is large, so I need some code that is as efficient as possible. I defined an 'is_a_neighbor' function to check if there is overlap between two ID's. It returns 'True' if two ID's are connected (i.e. have an overlap). I suppose I'll need to embed it in a loop somehow. Here's the function:

```
def is_a_neighbor(id_1, id_2):
  val = np.isin(df[df['ID'] == id_1][['Number']].to_numpy(), df[df['ID'] == id_2][['Number']].to_numpy()).any()
  return val
```

and a test run

```
# Test is_a_neighbor function
id_1 = 1
id_2 = 2

val = is_a_neighbor(id_1, id_2)
val
```

Which will return 'True'. Thanks for any help/guidance on this one.

Comment: Have you considered using a graph dedicated library like NetworkX ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work:

```py
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4], 
                   'Number':[234, 43, 455, 112, 45, 234, 982, 41, 112, 46, 109, 4]})

df.ID = df.ID.astype(str)
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'ID','Number')
connected_components = nx.connected_components(g)
d = {y:i for i, x in enumerate(connected_components) for y in x}

df['group'] = df.ID.replace(d)
df.ID = df.ID.astype(int)
```

The reason why we convert the `ID` column to a string is because we want `1` in the `ID` column to be distinct from `1` in the `Number` column.

If we didn't do that the following example would show only one group:

| ID | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |

To expand on the speed of the code, the following test resulted in an average time 3.4 seconds:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import timeit

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.random.randint(0, 10000, 10000), 
                        'Number': np.random.randint(0, 10000, 10000)})

def add_group(df):
    df.ID = df.ID.astype(str)
    g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'ID','Number')
    connected_components = nx.connected_components(g)
    d = {y:i for i, x in enumerate(connected_components) for y in x}

    df['group'] = df.ID.replace(d)
    df.ID = df.ID.astype(int)
    return df

timeit.timeit(lambda : add_group(test_df), number=100)
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you have a long list of pairs (Id, Number) and two different Id's belong to the same Group if there is any number N such that both (i1, N) and (id2, N) exist.

I don't know why you think you need either panda or numpy for this

Why not something like:

```
data = [(1, 234), (1, 43), (1, 455), (1, 112), (2, 234), ...]


# Create sets of numbers for each index

number_sets = {}
for (index, number) in data:
    # if we've not seen the index before we create an empty set
    if index not in number_sets:
        number_sets[index] = set()

    number_sets[index].add(number)
```

Now we create a list of groups where for each group we record a list of indices and the set of a numbers found with any of those indices

```
groups = []
    
for (index, numbers) in number_sets.items():
    for (index_list, superset) in groups:
        # if any of the numbers are in the superset then this index belongs to this group
        if not superset.isdisjoint(numbers):
           index_list.append(index)
           superset.join(numbers)
           break
    else:
        # We never had a break so we've found a new group
        groups.append(([index], numbers))
```